# Is it possible to transit through Orly Airport with two separate tickets?

Tags: transit, paperwork, france, ory

I'm Algerian and U.S. Permanent Resident, I have a repatriation flight booking from ORY to Algiers Airport and a Separate ticket from JFK to ORY passing through CASABLANCA Airport (Morrocco), I was wondering If I'll be let to board in.
Thank you for your answers.
All flights are operated by Royal Air Morocoo, and Air Algerie from Orly to Algiers.

Comment: I suppose you will have checked luggage? That necessarily implies going through immigration and a Schengen visa.

Comment: Without a Schengen visa, you probably won't even be allowed to board the flight in JFK.

Comment: @jcaron probably? sure or not ?

Comment: According to Timatic, you can only transit without a visa if you stay in the international transit area of the airport, and TWOV does not apply to certain arrival/departure terminal combinations https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true

Answer (score 3):

The check-in staff at JFK won't allow it. Not just for luggage reasons, but above all because, if anything goes awry with your connection, you're not "insured" and would be stuck in transit; unless you pay for a new connection, the inbound airline would end up having to take you back, a scenario they won't risk.